# How to navigate back on tvOS?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv

I have UITabBarController as rootView. For example I have 4 tab screens: 
A, B, C and D. When I navigate from Tab B to detailed tab B1 (via navigationController) I can't go to tab B using Apple TV remote. Does anyone knows how to navigate back? When I swipe left, it goes to A view, when I swipe right from A view - it goes to detailed B1 view and no Back button appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. On tvOS, you have to press Menu button to navigate upper in the hierarchy.

Refer to Buttons section in [tvOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/remote-and-interaction/#buttons).

Answer (score 1):

In tvOS there is nothing called back button. If you want to go to previous page you can press MENU button else if you want to switch between tabs you can use TabBarController which takes you directly to the different view controller